# Return SUM of all columns in a row dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, for-loop

Is there a way of summing the value of each column returned in a row dynamically using T-SQL?  I'm using SQL Server 2008.  I would imagine there's some sort of Table Valued Function magic that can accomplish this but I haven't been lucky in my search for an answer.

The data comes in like this:

```
id        type        value      date
1         PROD1       5          2014-08
2         PROD2       3          2014-08
3         PROD3       4          2014-08
4         PROD4       3          2014-08
5         PROD2       3          2014-07
6         PROD3       5          2014-06
```

And a TVF that accepts the date as a parameter and returns :

```
PROD1 PROD2   PROD3   PROD4
5     3       4       3
```

Now of course I can just run the following on the original table:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE date = '2014-08'
```

and get back

```
id        type        value      date
1         PROD1       5          2014-08
2         PROD2       3          2014-08
3         PROD3       4          2014-08
4         PROD4       3          2014-08
```

but...  I need to run some math on these values.  I might need to combine the sum of PROD1 and PROD3 or maybe get the percentage of SUM(PROD1,PROD3) over the total SUM.

I don't want to have do this

```
SELECT *,
  SUM(
    SELECT SUM(value) 
    FROM tbl 
    WHERE [date] = '2014-08'
    AND ( [type] = 'PROD1' OR [type] = 'PROD3')
  ) AS [SUM_P1+P3],

 SUM(
    SELECT SUM(value) 
    FROM tbl 
    WHERE [date] = '2014-08'
  ) AS [TOTAL_PROD],

 -- Percentage of (PROD1+PROD3)
 (
   SUM(
      SELECT SUM(value) 
      FROM tbl 
      WHERE [date] = '2014-08'
      AND ( [type] = 'PROD1' OR [type] = 'PROD3')
   ) AS [SUM_P1+P3],
   /
   SUM(
      SELECT SUM(value) 
      FROM tbl 
      WHERE [date] = '2014-08'
   )
 ) AS [PCT_P1+P3]

 ...
```

The vertical view saves me the trouble of having to constantly requery the database.  Manually adding each column into the SQL query is not an option as the table's width may vary.  It also just feels clunky that I would have to manually write out (V1+V2+V3+V4...) How would I go about iterating through each column in T-SQL?  Is there something similar to a for loop like this?

```
DECLARE @mysum int;
for(col in row) {
  SET @mysum = @mysum+col;
}
```

**Bonus points if I there's a way to detect if the column datatype is an integer.

Comment: You need to refer to INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS view and build the SQL query dynamically.

Comment: Create a view once and use it everytime you need sum of all columns

Comment: This question strikes me as a little bit of an XY problem. Could you explain a little of the bigger picture of what you are trying to accomplish? Namely, 1)why are you adding arbitrarily across columns in a row; 2)why do you not explicitly know the table's schema; and 3)why would you do this in the database engine as opposed to the presentation layer?

Comment: I'll do my best.

1) Maybe I'm doing it wrong.  I've added a little bit more detail on how the data comes in.

2) At this time, I can control everything, but as I hand this off, there is a good chance that more PROD columns will be added and I'm trying to keep this as dynamic as possible.

3) Baking these values back into the database is an eventuality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should reply to lc's comments as its very relevant, but you can achieve this with dynamic SQL.

```
USE mydatabase
DECLARE 
    @table varchar(max) = 'myTable',
    @exec nvarchar(max);

select
    @exec = 'select SUM('+RIGHT(c,LEN(c)-1)+') from '+@table
from (
    select
        '+'+c.name 
    from sys.columns c
    inner join sys.tables t on
        c.object_id = t.object_id
    inner join sys.types ty on
        c.user_type_id = ty.user_type_id
    where
        ty.name in ('int') and
        t.name = PARSENAME(@table,1)
    FOR XML PATH('')
) T (c)
print @exec
exec sp_executesql @exec
```

Comment: This definately works.  I'm still open to suggestions if anyone can find a simpler solution than what I've described.

Comment: @RyanDunphy if you want more suggestions I'd recommend leaving this unanswered for a day or two.  People are more likely to look at unanswered questions.